# Modal Displayed but show.bs.modal not fired

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

My Bootstrap modal gets displayed successfully, but the `show.bs.modal` event isn't getting fired for some reason.

Here is my modal markup:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="email-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>hi</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
$('#email-modal').on('show-bs-modal', function (event) {

        alert('hello, world!');

});
 $('#email-modal').modal();
```

[fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/8ud2hnt4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple typo:

FROM:  **show-bs-modal**  TO:  **show.bs.modal**

```js
$('#email-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    console.log('hello, world!');

});
$('#email-modal').modal();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="email-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>hi</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IsaacKleinman No. More then 30 years ago I wrote in pascal **procedure** with the zero instead of letter O. All the college went crazy.....to help me....

Comment: :D that's a great one!